# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28 Incorrect syntax near ')'. in my common table

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL server management studio 2014. And i keep receiving this error when creating a common table:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What I'm trying to do is to select the name and multiply two other columns attributes values to create an alias from the FIRE_FIGHTER table and make it a common table to be reused later on.

I was told to put a semicolon right at the beginning of the "WITH" keyword but it doesn't help. Please I'm new in SQL server. Can anyone help? Please. Thanks in advanced

```
;WITH PROMOTION_SCORE (F_Name,Promotion_Score)

AS

(

SELECT 
F_Name, (Years_In_Department*Number_Fire_Fought) AS Promotion_Score

 FROM FIRE_FIREGHTER

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your common table expression query syntax is wrong. You are missing the select statement. Try the following

```
;WITH PROMOTION_SCORE (F_Name,Promotion_Score)

AS

(

SELECT 
F_Name, (Years_In_Department*Number_Fire_Fought) AS Promotion_Score

 FROM FIRE_FIREGHTER

)
Select * from PROMOTION_SCORE;
```

Comment: How can I reuse the PROMOTION_SCORE to calculate the maximum Promotion_Score. I tried the following code right after the above mentioned one but it didn't work:

Comment: SELECT F_Name ,MAX(Promotion_Score) AS Highest_Promotion_Score FROM PROMOTION_SCORE It says : Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid object name 'PROMOTION_SCORE'.

Comment: I would like to know how to reuse the PROMOTION_SCORE common table more than once for further calculations in other queries

Comment: @Freddy, you can replace the Select * from PROMOTION_SCORE query with the query what you wanted to use. Promotion_Score will act as table in this context.

Comment: Thank you Kiran. I got it. I added the following code and It worked.

Comment: Select F_NAME,Promotion_Score FROM PROMOTION_SCORE WHERE Promotion_Score =(
SELECT MAX(Promotion_Score) AS Highest_Score FROM PROMOTION_SCORE);

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, the semicolon is a statement terminator. It's not so much that it should be BEFORE the CTE as it should be AFTER the previous statement. There are times when you don't want the semicolon before the CTE. For example:
create view products.specials as
with my_cte as
(
...
)
SELECT
...

In most cases the semicolon isn't required in tSQL but it is when a statement is followed by a CTE.

Comment: A nice example but not an answer to this question! Can I suggest you post it [over here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/23371/3690)?